# getting different unix timestamps in php and javascript ( server time is wrong )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

basically im trying to get equivalent of php `time()`  in javascript

here is the code :

```
var jstamp =  Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) ;
var pstamp =  <?php echo time(); ?>;

console.log( 'jstamp is : '+ jstamp);
console.log( 'pstamp is : '+ pstamp);
```

here is the result :

```
jstamp is : 13939 45587
pstamp is : 13939 33954
```

they are way different in the last 5 digits

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

result :

```
UTC2014-03-04 11:57:13
```

server time seems to be wrong , but shouldn't be wrong for both php and js ? meaning that still shouldn't i get the same result in both of them ?

Comment: Server timezone settings?

Comment: Bad clock setting on client?

Comment: you should check which one is correct, but I guess your server is just set to a different timezone

Comment: @dfsq i've added the timezone setting

Comment: Try to set the timezone on UTC: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: @Piskvor server time seems to be wrong , but shouldn't be wrong for both php and js ? meaning that still shouldn't i get the same result in both of them ?

Comment: @max your browser (javascript) time will is generated using the time on your computer, it does not have anything to do with the server.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts thanks , i wish i could chose your comment as the answer !

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be the timezone of your server. You can manually set it in PHP: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php